# How can I count rows base in several ranges in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with 2 columns like:

```
mm6 8
mm6 1
mm6 15
mm6 30
mm9 2
mm6 20
mm6 12
```

I am trying to make a script in awk to extract how many rows there are within a range.
for now I have :

```
awk    { if ($2 >= 1 && $2 <= 20) print $1 " " $2}
```

in the output I get all rows that fall into that range

```
mm6 8
mm6 1
mm6 15
mm9 2
mm6 20
mm6 12
```

but now I am trying to make awk to count how many rows I have for each piece of 10 units until it reaches a determined value, 100 for example.

I expected a output like this:

```
mm6 10 2
mm6 20 3
mm9 10 1
```

Explanation: mm6 has between 1-10 2 values, mm6 has between 11-20 3 values, mm9 has between 1-10 1 value

I am stuck, can someone help?

Comment: Sorry but this will take longer than I can spare. I don't see an easy way to generalize processing a group of ranges, i.e. 10-20, 20-30, 30-40, .... 90-100, .... ? Where does it end? Taking down my answer, as it is for a different sort of problem. Good luck. The `awk` patrol may be taking a holiday, but they'll be back with some good ideas. Good luck.

Comment: And plus-one for much improved question. Good luck.

Comment: When I was trying to write smth, I thougth in make a variable to define in the begining of the script for example:

awk  -v range=10 -v end=100 -f script.awk file

Comment: variables for ranges, Yes, I had thought of that, but how to cycle thru all possibilities is eluding me now. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience! If I get sucess I post it here.

Comment: @shellter ....awk patrols for sure..it's hard to keep up with them..lol

Comment: I think I have a pretty easy solution now in mind now, but don't have time tonight to work on it. Will try tomorrow. THe idea is to create `arr["mm6" , 10]++` but have the 10 be a variable that is calculated as `($2/range)+1*range` . So where $2=3, then 3/10 == 1 * 10 == 10. Getting that to work for corner cases and reasonable values for range like 10, 100, 10000000, 1000000000, will take extra testing. If this makes sense (to anyone), feel free to work it out. Good luck to all and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

using your first input

```
$ awk '{a[$1 FS 10*int(($2-1)/10)+10]++}
    END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file                       

mm6 10 2
mm6 20 3
mm6 30 1
mm9 10 1
```

you can add filters before or after.

Explanation: We create a key to count and print the key with counts at the end.  The key is two parts, first the identifier the second is the mapping of the ranges to bins.  For example to map 0-9 to 0, 10-19 to 1 you can divide by 10 and use the integer part.  Your ranges are from 1-10 so subtract one before dividing by 10; your bins are multiples of 10, so multiply by 10. also you use upper bound so add 10.

Comment: Karakfa! Amazing!! I would never get this right. So a simple script. I was thinking too more complicate. Thank you for your help. I need now to study this to learn how this work.

Comment: Karakfa, could you explain to me what each piece of the script do ?